# Office 365 Calendar API Event Creation

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-calendar

I am integrating Office 365 with my application. When I create an event on Office 365 Calendar, it sends emails to all the attendees. How to disable this? I don't want to send the mails when an event is created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is still no solution to this. You can follow this thread for more information: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/286611-office-365-groups/suggestions/9532698-allow-calendar-appointments-to-be-created-without. Check the comments!

Comment: This is fixed. Look at my response

Answer (score 0):

On MS Graph there is `eventCreationOptions` on beta API versions. Look into this.

```
<ComplexType Name="eventCreationOptions">
  <Property Name="saveToGroupCalendarOnly" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
 </ComplexType>
```

Comment: Its been removed now. [ChangeLog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog#april-2017)

Comment: If you are referring to the following then that only applies to in tune: Removed the following complex types:
applePushNotificationCertificateSetting
eventCreationOptions